# Placing two "yield"s next to each other in Dart (Flutter), only the second get executed

Tags: flutter, yield, bloc

In Flutter, I am making a Login/Signup page using BLoC pattern and Firebase. After signing up user, I am sending a verification email and changing the state to "VerificationEmailSentState" (so I can show a SnackBar and switch to Login page in PageView) and then re-changing it to the initial state (InitialState). The problem is that it's jumping directly to the InitialState without going thro VerificationEmailSentState hence not showing the SnackBar or switching to Login page!

When I debugged the code I found out that it's actually changing the state to (VerificationEmailSentState) but then immediately changing it back to InitialState so the code inside the BlocBuilder is not getting executed because it's being interrupted (re-Built) when I am changing the state to InitialState. To make sure, I put a delay of 1-second after changing the state the first time and it worked (the SnackBar appeared).

The question is Why is this happening? and is delaying the second change in the state a good idea? if no, how to get it working without it?

```
//SignupBloc
await user.sendEmailVerification();
yield SignupVerificationEmailSentState();
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)); //Will not work without it.
yield SignupInitialState();
```

```
//LoginSignupPage
BlocBuilder<SignupEvent, SignupState>(
      bloc: _signupBloc,
      builder: (BuildContext context, SignupState state) {
        if (state is SignupVerificationEmailSentState) {
          print("About to show SnackBar");//Printed only with delay
          raiseSnackBar();
          swtichToLogin();
        }
        return ...
      }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually the behavior you are asking it to do. You are yielding a state (`SignupVerificationEmailSentState`) and then immediately changing it back to another state `SignupInitialState`.

You are calling `raiseSnackBar()` when the state `is SignupVerificationEmailSentState`, which is correct, but then, as you pointed, the view is being rebuilt because you are actually reverting it back with not enough time for the user to see the `SnackBar`. The `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1))` is actually giving it a second of time to show it.

This is not a "bad approach", it will depend of your app's flow and what you are actually trying to achieve. However, I would rather do

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) => yield SignupInitialState());
```

which won't prevent any other instructions to run after that one within that method call, assuming that you might have some. If you don't, that's fine.

If you want to make sure that it only reverts to its initial state after the `SnackBar` is shown for 1 second, remove those these two lines:

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)); //Will not work without it.
yield SignupInitialState();
```

and you can do it with something like this:

```
  Scaffold.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text('Something...'),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              ),
            )
            .closed
            .then((_) => bloc.revertToSignupInitialState());
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
My only concern is that I am not 100% sure 1-second is enough because I think it depends on the hardware and how much time does it take to execute all the statements inside `BlocBuilder`.

Comment: @AmerAlahmar I've edited my answer with an example that does exactly what you want. It shows the `SnackBar` and then, when it is dismissed (closed), it will call a ` bloc.revertToSignupInitialState()` which can be a method that yields back to that state.